# xmlvm my android to iphone project

Tags: java, android, ios

I have a working android app, I now have a new mac for the sole purpose of developing the same app on iphone.  I have installed xmlvm on the mac and I moved by android app into the workspace and when I try and cross compile I get an error - could not find input resource: bin.  Anybody here using xmlvm to cross compile android apps?  Can you help with this error?  There is a bin folder in my Test_One project.

```
pwd /Users/iosdev/Documents/workspace/xmlvm/Test_One

/Users/iosdev

iOS-Mac-mini:~ iosdev$ java -Xmx700m -jar /Users/iosdev/Documents/workspace/xmlvm/dist/xmlvm.jar --in=bin --out=out --target=iphonec --app-name=testone

[03/11/12 10:00:19.281]    ERROR: InputProcessFactory: Could not find input resource: bin

[03/11/12 10:00:19.290]    ERROR: XmlvmProcessor: No inputs to process.

[03/11/12 10:00:19.290]    ERROR: Something went wrong during processing.

iOS-Mac-mini:~ iosdev$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `in=bin/`, or with `--in=bin/*`. The problem is simple: It can't find the "bin"-resource, I guess it thinks of it as a file and not a directory.